# Python, having trouble converting my code into a while loop

Tags: python

Took on a personal web scraping project to teach myself python but after parsing my data (age/sex of a profile), I am having trouble turning it into a while loop, no matter how I reformat my code it gives me different errors, without the for loop the code works on only one page, I need it to loop through pages until the length of my list reaches 40.

```
link_list = 0
page_num = 1
while (len(link_list)) < 40:
    page_link = ('https://google.com/page=' + str(page))
    browser.get(page_link)
    age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')
    page = page + 1
    link_sex_candidates = (
        (ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href'),
         ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text)
        for ii in age_sex
    )
link_sex_filtered = [
    (link, sex) 
    for link, sex in link_sex_candidates 
    if sex[2:3] != 'F'
]
link_list = [link for link, sex in link_sex_filtered]
sex_list = [sex for link, sex in link_sex_filtered]
```

---

```
 Error Message:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\artur\Desktop\do not delete final.py", line 31, in <module>
 while (len(link_list)) < 40:
 TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I know what this error message means and I thought it would be corrected if I defined link_list outside of the while loop. I am grateful and thankfully for any help that you can give.

Edit: Someone asked me for the code before the while loop was introduced:

```
age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')

link_sex_candidates = (
    (ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href'),
     ii.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text)
    for ii in age_sex
)
link_sex_filtered = [
    (link, sex)
    for link, sex in link_sex_candidates
    if sex[2:3] != 'F'
]
link_list = [link for link, sex in link_sex_filtered]
sex_list = [sex for link, sex in link_sex_filtered]
```

Comment: Share the first version, without the loop, indentation is strange here

Comment: Also, you're getting this error because you're trying to find the length (`len()`) of an integer, and integer is not a list.

Comment: That'st from my mistake from editing it too much, earlier when I had it link_list = ['test'] it would keep running until I shut it down.

Comment: Added code before the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this ? Here I am using range() instead of your while where you are counting up. The way you wrote it I didnt see a point in having both page_num and link_list as you didnt really use link_list. Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

```
link_list = []
sex_list = []
page = 1

while len(link_list) < 40:
    page_link = ('https://google.com/page=' + str(page))
    browser.get(page_link)
    age_sex = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//*[@class="lh-copy truncate silver"]')
    for item in age_sex:
        link = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//a').get_attribute('href')
        sex = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
        if sex[2:3] != 'F':
            link_list.append(link)
            sex_list.append(sex)
    page += 1

print(link_list)
```

Edit: Edited my answer to use while instead of for as it should stop at 40 occurances not go through 40 pages individually.

Edit2: Only adding matching results to link_list

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I understand what you were trying to do but I do not need it to repeat my function forty times arbitrarily. I need it to repeat until the length of link_list has 40 values within it which could take as quick as two pages. With your function, it goes through 40 pages regardless of the length of link_list.

Comment: @ArturPodlesniy I edited my answer to stop at 40 items in link_sex_candidates. I am unsure which information you want to be in link_list because you just initialize it with a 0 and dont use it in your example code. Is this more like what you want to do ? This loops until link_sex_candidates has found 40 appearances.

Comment: link_sex_candidates is all returns of the search function labelled age_sex. 
                                                                                                                
 Age_sex values is what the script is parsing to see if the profile is male or female, if female, it deletes the profile from both link_list and sex_list.

Comment: link_list contains the values after Age_sex has already been adjusted.   Where as link_sex_candidates returns every instance that is found without removing the profiles that need to be deleted. So for example, with your updated code, it runs through multiple pages but stops after it has found forty instances of age_sex, does that make sense?

Comment: @ArturPodlesniy In that case I would add the filter directly to the loop instead of filtering afterwards and only append to the list if it is a match. I edited my answer again, this should be what you were looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You fail immediately because `link_list` is an integer when you try to enter the `while` loop.  It has no length; it's a scalar.  It's not a list until after you exit the loop.  Nowhere in the loop do you accumulate those links; you need to sort out your logic: what is done anew each time through the loop, what is filtered, and what gets accumulated, one iteration at a time.

Comment: That'st from my mistake from editing it  too much,  earlier when I had it link_list = ['test'] it would keep running until I shut it down.